# How to "auto-schedule" the execution of a endpoint calling it using celery?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, celery

I've a application using Flask and Celery. Right now I have a endpoint called "/get-products", but I want it to be schedule when I call it.

What I want is call that endpoint, and it schelude itself, without trigge other function or anything

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the general idea:

Create a function that will do the actual processing in a function named, for example, `get_products_task` and decorate it with `@celery_task`. Then your endpoint function for /get-products will determine how many seconds in the future it wishes to run the the celery task and schedule it accordingly. For example:

```py
@celery_task
get_products_task():
    with app.app_context(): # if an application context is required
        ...


@app.route('/get-products')
def get_products():
    task = get_products_task.apply_async(countdown=120)
    return render_template('schedule_get_products_template.html'), 202
    #return '/get-products has been scheduled!', 202
```

If the /get_products endpoint is to be called sometimes without delay, then its logic **really should be factored out into a separate function**, for example,`get_products_logic`:

```py
def get_products_logic():
    """
    The actual logic for getting products.
    The assumption is that an application context exists, if necessary.
    """
    ...
        
@celery_task
def get_products_task():
    with app.app_context(): # if an application context is required
        get_products_logic()

@app.route('/get-products')
def get_products():
    get_products_logic()
    return reneder_template('get_products_template.html'), 200

@app.route('/schedule-get-products')
def schedule_get_products():
    task = get_products_task.apply_async(countdown=120)
    return render_template('schedule_get_products_template.html'), 202
    #return '/get-products has been scheduled!', 202
```